# How to fix the field error issue in django?

Tags: postgresql, bootstrap-4, django-2.0

I try to navigate from list page to detail page, when i tried with the below code. I got error stating that field error. For that I've tried with adding a empty Slug field in models, it shows an page not found error.

[image]

```
 #urls.py
 from django.urls import path

 from .views import (TaskListView,TaskDetailView)


 app_name = 'Tasks'


 urlpatterns = [

     path('', TaskListView.as_view(), name='list'),
     path('<slug:slug>/', TaskDetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
  ] 



 #views.py
 from django.shortcuts import render
 from django.http import HttpResponse
 # Create your views here.
 from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView, View

 from .models import Taskmanager


 def home(request):
   return render(request, 'home.html')


 class TaskListView(ListView):
  template_name = 'Tasks.html'
  model = Taskmanager
  context_object_name = 'data'


 class TaskDetailView(DetailView):
   template_name = 'detail.html'
   model = Taskmanager
   context_object_name = 'data'


 #models.py
 from django.db import models
 from django.urls import reverse

 # Create your models here.
 week_number = (("week01", "week01"),
           ("week02", "week02"),
           ("week03", "week03"),
           ("week04", "week04"),
           ("week05", "week05"),
           ("week06", "week06"),
           ("week07", "week07"),
           ("week08", "week08"),
           ("week09", "week09"),
           ("week10", "week10"),
           ("week11", "week11"),
           ("week12", "week12"),
           ("week13", "week13"),
           ("week14", "week14"),
           ("week15", "week15"),
           ("week16", "week16"),
           ("week17", "week17"),
           ("week18", "week18"),
           ("week19", "week19"),
           ("week20", "week20"),
           ("week21", "week21"),
           ("week22", "week22"),
           ("week23", "week23"),
           ("week24", "week24"),
           ("week25", "week25"),
           ("week26", "week26"),
           ("week27", "week27"),
           ("week28", "week28"),
           ("week29", "week29"),
           ("week30", "week30"),
           ("week31", "week31"),
           ("week32", "week32"),
           ("week33", "week33"),
           ("week34", "week34"),
           ("week35", "week35"),
           ("week36", "week36"),
           ("week37", "week37"),
           ("week38", "week38"),
           ("week39", "week39"),
           ("week40", "week40"),
           ("week41", "week41"),
           ("week42", "week42"),
           ("week43", "week43"),
           ("week44", "week44"),
           ("week45", "week45"),
           ("week46", "week46"),
           ("week47", "week47"),
           ("week48", "week48"),
           ("week49", "week49"),
           ("week50", "week50"),
           ("week51", "week51"),
           ("week52", "week52"),
           ("week53", "week53"),

           )
class Taskmanager(models.Model):
   CurrentSprint = models.CharField(max_length=10, default="week01", 
   choices=week_number)
   todaydate = models.DateField()
   taskname = models.SlugField(max_length=200)
   testrun = models.URLField(max_length=300)
   comments = models.CharField(max_length=300)
   assignedto = models.EmailField(max_length=70)



   def __str__(self):
      return self.taskname

   def get_absolute_url(self):
      return reverse('Tasks:detail', kwargs={'slug': self.taskname})


 #Tasks.html
 <a href="{% url 'Tasks:detail' slug='detail'%}"> {{Taskmanager.todaydate}} 
 </a>
```

I need an output when I click the link, it needs to navigate to the details page where the details of the task needs to be displayed.

Comment: Any update on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding this

```
#views.py
class TaskDetailView(DetailView):
...
def get_object(self):
    instance = get_object_or_404(Taskmanager, slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
    return instance

#models.py
django.db.models.signals import pre_save

class Taskmanager(models.Model):
    ...
    taskname = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100)
    ...

    def pre_save_Taskmanager_receiver(instance, *args, **kwargs):
        if not instance.slug:
            instance.slug = instance.taskname

    pre_save.connect(pre_save_Taskmanager_receiver, sender= Taskmanager)

# task.html
<a href="{% url 'Tasks:detail' slug=data.slug %}"> {{ data.todaydate }}</a>
```

Comment: Hi @Mint. Sorry for responding late. Now I get the 404 error page. how to avoid this?

Comment: You're getting the error for non-existing objects or existing objects?

Comment: check my updated answer. make sure when you save your instance you include a taskname so the slug will be created.

Comment: Got this error "pre_save_Taskmanager_receiver() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'"

Comment: is self in the definition? `def pre_save_Taskmanager_receiver(self, instance, *args, **kwargs):`

Comment: Yes @Mint. def pre_save_Taskmanager_receiver(self, instance, *args, 
                       **kwargs):
                      if not self.slug:
                           self.slug = self.taskname
                      pre_save.connect(pre_save_Taskmanager_receiver, sender= Taskmanager)

Comment: how did you create the object? tryin shell?

Comment: Exception Type: TypeError at /admin/Tasks/taskmanager/add/
Exception Value: pre_save_Taskmanager_receiver() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Comment: No in the django  admin page

Comment: change `self` to `instance`. sorry about that, at work.

Comment: Ah, now the objects are saved in database. But still getting the 404 error.

Comment: Does the problem with the html file. `  <a href="{{ tasks.get_absolute_url}}"> {{tasks.todaydate}} </a> `

Comment: change to `<a href="{% url 'detail' %}"> {{tasks.todaydate}} </a>`

Comment: Getting NameError: name 'Taskmanager' is not defined in models.py

Comment: Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError at /Tasks/
Exception Value: Could not parse the remainder: '=' from '='

Comment: remove the spaces.

Comment: Ahh. It Works @Mint. Thanks for your patience :-)

Comment: But why we used pre-save signal instead of post-save signal, is there any reason?  Can i know it  for learning purpose?

Comment: I use the pre_save signal that way I can make the slug field required. However we didn't require the field in this case but you may want to make that adjustment.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mint